# How can I run minikube on a centos VM?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

So, I am trying to install minikube on my laptop. I have a windows 7 machine on which I have installed VMware work station and created a centos 7 machine. On that centos machine I want to install minikube. I have followed few steps and installed all the dependencies but finally # minikube start is giving error

```
[root@localhost ~]# minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE="X.X.X.X/24" --container-runtime=docker --extra-config kubelet.EnableCustomMetrics=true
There is a newer version of minikube available (v0.33.1).  Download it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v0.33.1

To disable this notification, run the following:
minikube config set WantUpdateNotification false
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 140.01 MB / 140.01 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s

E0214 04:21:19.799121   16837 start.go:150] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Creating VM.
: Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded.

 Retrying.
E0214 04:21:19.813063   16837 start.go:156] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Creating VM.
: Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded
```

Comment: I don't think you can run minikube (it is a vm) in a centos vm.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run Minikube (like @BMW stated in his comment) into another VM in the way you are doing it.

You have couple of options to resolve your issue:

1) Try to use `minikube start --vm-driver=none` instead of `minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox` in your current installation

2) You can run Minikube on your Windows 7 machine without using additional Linux VM.
An example of the installation, can be found in the [Deploying minikube on Windows 7](https://blog.darkedges.com/2016/12/21/minikube-windows/) article. It uses [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) as a main resource of minikube during the installation